# How to fix 'bodyParser' is declared but its value is never read.ts(6133) error on Axios and Body-Parser?

Tags: javascript, axios, request, body-parser

I'm taking a course on web development and this is something I know nothing about. I started to write my js code just like on the lesson and I've done these steps before but as installing request I got an error with "request has been deprecated". So I search about it and installed axios. After that, when I write the code on my js file, on axios and body parser shows this error "bodyParser' is declared but its value is never read.ts(6133)". I have no idea what could be.

This is the code:

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const axios = require("axios");



app.listen(3000,function(){
  console.log("Server is runing on port 3000");
});
```

when I try the load the server it shows
"Usage: nodemon [nodemon options] [script.js] [args]

See "nodemon --help" for more."

Answer (score 0):

You are using a variable called `app` (in the `app.listen()`) which you haven't initialised as being an `express` app. After your `require` statements you should include the following line:

```js
  const app = express();
```

This allows you to use the `listen()` method as you've used. Besides that, I think you should pass the `bodyParser` as a middleware using `app.use()`:

```js
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

This will allow you access to the `req` object from which you can access the body of the request to do as you wish. The root of the issue is that you are requiring packages that you are not using.